# How do I read a cookie in another Controller using c#.net?

Tags: c#, cookies

I have created the cookie from another controller and I can see it present in the browser, and now Im trying read a Cookie in another Controller in my Project but the word Cookies in *Request.Cookies["MyCookie"];* is underlined red with the error saying:

> Error 5: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Cookies' and no extension method 'Cookies' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Security;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Project.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : ApiController
    {

        public String getCookie()
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["MyCookie"];
            string username;

            if(  cookie != null)
            {
                username = Request.Cookies["MyCookie"].Value;
            }

            return username;
        }
```

Im still new in C# .Net and I dont know how to solve this problem at all. Im using Visual Studio 2013. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
string username="";
var cookie = Request.Headers.GetCookies("MyCookie").SingleOrDefault();

if (cookie != null)
{
    username = cookie["MyCookie"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage` object does not contain a cookies object. To access cookies in a WebAPI controller you need to look at the Request.Headers object like so:

```
CookieHeaderValue clientCookie = 
        Request.Headers.GetCookies("MyCookie").SingleOrDefault();
string username = clientCookie["MyCookie"].Value;
```

Comment: Thanks! This approach worked, too. I cant upvote yet, though. I still lack some "reputation" for it.